# Is the tag "7.1-nougat" necessary?

Tags: discussion, tags

This one comes to mind after seeing [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/167285/full-disk-encryption-on-google-pixel-xl-vs-google-nexus-6p).

Historically almost every bump of [Android API version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_version_history) warrants a new tag, but when Android 4.0.3 dawned as a "minor" version of Android 4.0 *but* comes with API15 instead of API14, there's no designated tag for it. I assume this is because that the lifespan of API14 is too short (2 months) to be of use to discussion, thus [4.0-ice-cream-sandwich](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/4.0-ice-cream-sandwich) remains.

Now, minus the preview period, Android 7.0 (API24) has a lifespan even shorter than that of API14, then gave way to Android 7.1 (API25). In this sense Android 7.1 is definitely the way to go in future discussions. Should we create this tag and make [7.0-nougat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/7.0-nougat) a synonym to it, or the other way round?

Comment: The incremental versions of 4.0 were extremely minor IIRC, and the vast majority of questions about one apply to the other.  I don't know exactly what changed between 7.0 and 7.1, but the versioning would indicate something more significant.  We should separate tags (or not) based on whether there was a significant change to the end user problem space, rather than APIs or lifespan.

Comment: @MatthewRead From the API wiki page I linked above, the only _major_ changes seem to be Seamless Updates and Daydream VR. I don't know if that warrants a separate creation. 5.1 doesn't have much improvements either but it does have a separate tag.

Comment: Seeing that the Daydream VR is new to 7.1, I guess it warrants the tag *when it's needed*. That specific question doesn't need it though.

Comment: I don't agree. Just make `7.1-nougat` a symlink(?) to `7.0-nougat` since they are all 'Android Nougat Family' like Lollipop and Ice Cream Sandwich do.

Comment: @iBug I mentioned "tag synonym" which I guess is what you mean. There isn't a conclusion made yet. Do not that, despite both Lollipop, 5.1 and 5.0 has separate tags because of the features 5.1 introduced. If Daydream and seamless got enough traction, it's still reasonable to create a separate one.